# Reinstalled Windows 7 can't get Smart card to work

Tags: windows-7, drivers, smartcard

I need a smart card to log in to work remotely. I've just reinstalled Windows on my desktop machine at home and inserted the smart card reader, but Windows is not detecting the drivers. I went to Device Manager and the Smart Card has a yellow exclamation mark on it. If I right click and select Update Driver Software, Windows is unable to install the Smart Card. I never had these issues before and it works fine on my laptop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled my antivirus (avast! free edition) and it now works fine. Grrr...